# Use ArrayList to populate mysql database row

Tags: java, mysql, database, arraylist

I need to add each item from the ArrayList to a database. I can get the for each loop to output each line item in the file to the console window, but how would I use this loop to add each item to a mysql database row?

```
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(file);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    ArrayList<String> store = new ArrayList<String>();
    String strLine;

    //Read File Line By Line
while((strLine = br.readLine())!= null)
{
    String [] splitLine = strLine.split(" \n");
    for(String x : splitLine)
    {

        System.out.println("Line: "+ x +"\n");

    }
}
```

------ Update ----

Ok, I have modified the code

```
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(file);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
    String strLine;

        while((strLine = br.readLine())!= null)
            {
                String [] splitLine = strLine.split(" \n");
                for(int i=0;i<splitLine.length;i++)
                {           
                    // Prepare the query and values to be inserted into the database 
                    String str="INSERT INTO donations(name,charity,amount) VALUES (?,?,?)";

                    java.sql.PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(str); 
                        String db1 = splitLine[0];
                        String db2 = splitLine[1];
                        Double db3 = Double.parseDouble(splitLine[2]);

                    statement.setString(1,db1);
                    statement.setString(2,db2);
                    statement.setDouble(3,db3);


                System.out.println("Line: "+ splitLine[i]+ " -record- " + i);

                }
            }
```

Comment: Time to learn jdbc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sig2=O8bURWq-gsHnhtDNK9DVlQ&bvm=bv.44158598,d.dmg

Comment: Replace the `System.out.println()` with the code to add to a database. Like @Lucas said, this will be done with `JDBC`.

Comment: I know how to establish the connection and I also understand about the prepared statement, I just can't figure out the necessary code to add the string values of the arraylist objects to each field of the database row and I have read the page you linked to several times and can't seem to get the code snippet worked out.

Comment: If you understand the `PreparedStatement` then all you need to do is to set each `x` as a parameter of your statement and then execute the statement to insert it.

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read a text file. You don't need it so please remove it as people might copy this code.

Answer (score 0):

you could use hibernate and create a POJO for the database table. You can create an arraylist of this POJO and upon save, the arraylist will be (bulk) inserted in the database.

Comment: You should provide some code examples (or at least a link to examples) for the OP.